# How to setup HMR on one bundle and Live reload on others with single server on Webpack 5 Multi-Compiler (array of configs) mode

Tags: webpack, build, bundle, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

We have a webpack project where we just watch files and serve files using a simple express server. Now we are trying to integrate webpack-dev-server into it .
We have a Multi-compiler webpack setup. There is a single "**App**" bundle and multiple other "**libraryXYZ**" bundles(who have dependencies on each other).

I want

- HMR to work properly on main "App" bundle .
- For the other "library" bundles I want to trigger a live reload .(Libraries are injected into main app programmatically as and when needed).

I am aware I could spin up different webpack servers for different bundles but I want to do it with a single webpack server for convenience. (The way codebase is currently setup would have to refactor a lot of things if multiple local servers are used for bundles)

Our current App config is somewhat like this (only the necessary details)

```
const AppConfig  = {
    name:'app',
    entry: { app: path.resolve(basePath,'/src/index.tsx') },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        hot:true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }, 
    output: { path: path.resolve(basePath, 'dist') },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                    options: {
                      plugins: [require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')],
                    },//able to achieve HMR for main App bundle using refresh
                  },
                ],
              }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.resolve('/src/index.html') }),
        new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin()
    ],
};
```

Our current LibraryXYZ config (Many more such  Libraries are there)

```
const LibraryXYZconfig = {
    name:'libraryxyz',
    dependencies:['libabc'],
    entry: {
        "main":path.resolve(basePath,'/src/libxyz/main.js'),
        "react-modify": path.resolve(basePath,"/src/libxyz/react-modify.js")
    },
    output: {  path: path.resolve(basePath, 'dist','libxyz')    },
};
```

And then in the end of course

```
module.exports = [appConfig,libxyzConfig,libAbCConfig,libDEFConfig];;
```

Now webpack states

> Be aware that when exporting multiple configurations only the
> devServer options for the first configuration will be taken into
> account and used for all the configurations in the array.

Which means i cant configure dev-server differently for each bundle . (Cant set hot:true for one false for other) .
What should my config rules look like to fit the use case?
Is this even some thing thats possible . Open to alternate ways to handle this.
Also if someone knows ways for making every bundle hot reload would also be interested in knowing that.(Although im not sure how that works).